# Django - Lazy results with a context processor

Tags: django

I am working on a django project that requires much of the common page data be dynamic. Things that appear on every page, such as the telephone number, address, primary contact email etc all need to be editable via the admin panel, so storing them in the settings.py file isn't going to work.

To get around this, I created a custom context processor which acts as an abstract reference to my "Live Settings" model. The model looks like this:

```
class LiveSetting(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

And the context processor like so:

```
from livesettings.models import LiveSetting

class LiveSettingsProcessor(object):
    def __getattr__(self, request):
        val = LiveSetting.objects.get(request)
        setattr(self, val.key, val.value)
        return val.value

l = LiveSettingsProcessor()

def livesetting_processors(request):
    return {'settings':l}
```

It works really nicely, and in my template I can use {{ settings.primary_email }} and get the corresponding value from the database.

The problem with the above code is it handles each live setting request individually and will hit the database each time my {{ settings.*}} tag is used in a template.

Does anyone have any idea if I could make this process lazy, so rather than retrieve the value and return it, it instead updates a QuerySet then returns the results in one hit just before the page is rendered?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Lazy load" of data from a context processor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563812/lazy-load-of-data-from-a-context-processor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to invent something complex and these is no reason for that. Something as simple as this will work fork you good enough:

```
def livesetting_processors(request):
    settings = LiveSetting.objects.get(request)
    return {'settings':settings}
```

EDIT:

This is how you will solve your problem in current implementation:

```
class LiveSettingsProcessor(object):
    def __getattr__(self, request):
        val = getattr(self, '_settings', LiveSetting.objects.get(request))
        setattr(self, val.key, val.value)
        return val.value
```

@Hanpan, I've updated my answer to show how you can to solve your problem, but what I want to say is that things you are trying to achieve does not give any practical win, however it increase complexity ant it takes your time. It might also be harder to setup cache on all of this later. And with caching enabled this will not give any improvements in performance at all.

I don't know if you heard this before: premature optimization is the root of evil. I think this thread on SO is useful to read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211414/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

Comment: Skirmantas, thanks for your reply. I will up rate and tick when the timer ends.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try [Django's caching](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/)?

In particular, you may want to check out the [low-level caching feature](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api). It seems like it would be a lot less work than what you plan on.

Comment: I will be caching the results when I push the site live, I'd still like to optimize the process thought so I can take the 10+ DB hits down to 1.

Comment: @Hanpan, what you have implemented is already a cache system. And it is totally wrong. You use `objects.get(request)` to get a value, then you set it on `self`. Instance of `LiveSettingsProcessor` I guess, is created when your server loads or when first request is made. Now when second request will be made, value from first request will be returned, however you make an illusion that objects are fetched on every request (by providing a request object to manager). And if my assumption of one instance of `LiveSettingsProcessor` per thread is wrong, then `LiveSettingsProcessor` is useless.

Comment: It's ok that the results are fetched every request, I just want the results to be returned as one query as opposed to running a query for each setting.

Comment: Then explain please, what is the purpose of `LiveSettingsProcessor` object.

Comment: Sorry if my original post is unclear. I am using LiveSettingsProcessor as a 'gateway' to my LiveSettings model. I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do and by your reaction, I'm guessing not. All I want to do is use code like this in my templates: {{ settings.some_key }} and get the 'some_key' value from my LiveSettings model. That in itself is simple enough to do, but when using more than one key in the same request ie: {{ settings.some_key1 }} and {{ settings.some_key2 }}, I 'd like to avoid hitting the database twice and instead retrieve all required settings in one filtered query.