# "Lazy load" of data from a context processor

Tags: django, caching, django-views, lazy-loading

In each view of my application I need to have navigation menu prepared. So right now in every view I execute complicated query and store the menu in a dictionary which is passed to a template. In templates the variable in which I have the data is surrounded with "cache", so even though the queries are quite costly, it doesn't bother me.

But I don't want to repeat myself in every view. I guessed that the best place to prepare the menu is in my own context processor. And so I did write one, but I noticed that even when I don't use the data from the context processor, the queries used to prepare the menu are executed. Is there a way to "lazy load" such data from CP or do I have to use "low level" cache in CP? Or maybe there's a better solution to my problem?

Comment: how about an if:else block in your context processor to check whether the data is needed or not?

Comment: you can write a custom tag, which is calculated only when used

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Django has a `SimpleLazyObject`. In Django 1.3, this is used by the [auth context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth) ([source code](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.3.1/django/contrib/auth/context_processors.py)). This makes `user` available in the template context for every query, but the user is only accessed when the template contains `{{ user }}`.

You should be able to do something similar in your context processor.

```
from django.utils.functional import SimpleLazyObject
def my_context_processor(request):
    def complicated_query():
        do_stuff()
        return result

    return {
        'result': SimpleLazyObject(complicated_query)
```

Answer (score 15):

If you pass a callable object into the template context, Django will evaluate it when it is used in the template. This provides one simple way to do laziness — just pass in callables:

```
def my_context_processor(request):
    def complicated_query():
        do_stuff()
        return result                      
    return {'my_info': complicated_query}
```

The problem with this is it does not memoize the call — if you use it multiple times in a template, `complicated_query` gets called multiple times.

The fix is to use something like `SimpleLazyObject` as in the other answer, or to use something like `functools.lru_cache`:

```
from functools import lru_cache:

def my_context_processor(request):
    @lru_cache()
    def complicated_query():
        result = do_stuff()
        return result                      
    return {'my_info': complicated_query}
```

You can now use `my_info` in your template, and it will be evaluated lazily, just once.

Or, if the function already exists, you would do it like this:

```
from somewhere import complicated_query

def my_context_processor(request):        
    return {'my_info': lru_cache()(complicated_query)}
```

I would prefer this method over `SimpleLazyObject` because the latter can produce some [strange bugs sometimes](https://code.djangoproject.com/search?q=SimpleLazyObject+bug&noquickjump=1&ticket=on).

(I was the one who originally implemented `LazyObject` and `SimpleLazyObject`, and discovered for myself that there is curse on any code artefact labelled [simple](https://github.com/django/django/blob/210d0489c5daad56b806f8165f9fe09fb3c2a019/django/utils/functional.py#L284).)