# Django included template's get doesn't get called

Tags: python, django

In my django application, I created a base template with some navigation items. I also {{ included }} another template that contains a form. I'd like this to be available on every page. This form template has a view that populates some elements from the database and I do this in view.get. But I discovered when I just {{ include }} the template, its view's get isn't ever called.

finances/base.html is the base template
finances/month_list.html is the template I'd like to include

base.html looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PFM</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navigation">
    <a href= "{% url 'finances:current_month' %}">Home</a><!--this month's transactions-->
    <a href= "{% url 'finances:accounts' %}">Liability Details</a><!--liability account details-->
    <a href= "{% url 'finances:accounts' %}">Asset Details</a><!-- asset account details-->
    <a href= "{% url 'finances:create' %}">New Account</a><!-- create an account-->
</div>

<div class="content">

    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}

</div>
<br/>
<div class="bottom_nav">
    {% include "finances/month_list.html" %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The rest of the code can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/shelbydz/6001359
(it's a lot of code, I hope linking it is okay)

Thanks,

Comment: The include starts from the folder your including template is on, so remove `finances` from `{% include 'finances/month_list.html' %}` and you should be fine. It's a common mistake, I suppose :D

Comment: Templates don't have views. The relationship is view->template, not the other way round (and in fact a view can render multiple templates, or none at all).

Answer (score 2):

It is normal that the view is not called. Actually this is because the template does not now about the view(one template may be used in many different views and other templates).

In your case there are two options - to create a context processor and to create a template tag. The context processor will add the required data for each view context so you will only need to add the template to each page. The template tag is another option - you create the logic in it and you can also pass the template as a variable. This way your app will be a bit more faster for pages that do not need this form.

Comment: The performance hit of the context processor approach can be solved by using lazy evaluation of some kind, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563812/lazy-load-of-data-from-a-context-processor

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine by using IIian IIiev solution. Context processor / template tags for pages.