# Django admin is loading pages incredibly slowly

Tags: python, django, postgresql, gunicorn, django-suit

I've got a django application with django suit running in a **gunicorn** server and it´s taking a lot of time to load every single page of the admin (both list and edit views). The list view of a table that has 1 single record with no foreign keys and no callables is taking 6-8 seconds, and the list view of a table paged to 50 elements is taking 25-30 seconds.

I've checked the executed SQLs thought the logging module with the following configuration and they seem to be OK, the total time of all the SQLs is about 2 tenths. The database is postgresql.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/opt/django/myproj/log/debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

I've also tried to disable **USE_I18N** and removed the **@never_cache** from the admin just in case, but nothing has changed.

Does anyone has any suggestion on what could be going on in my server?

Thanks!

My context processors:

```
from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS as TCP
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = TCP + (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n'
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would expect the total time of SQL to be **far** less than 1 second. If it isn't, are there lots of SQL queries? For an admin view like the one you've described, you should be looking at fewer than 10 SQL queries.

The number of SQL queries can have a big effect, because Django has to construct them and build the result set, and this time is not included in the times given for the SQL queries.

You should add the django-debug-toolbar and see if that gives some clues.

Other sources of slowness:

- context processors that are slow (e.g. do lots of DB queries), and are executed because they are in the global `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting. A solution is to remove them and only add them to views that need them, or use [laziness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563812/lazy-load-of-data-from-a-context-processor) so that they don't actually get evaluated unless needed.
- Something that is being added to the head of your HTML page and is loading slowly. Use your browser network debugger to check
- Something else server-side. Using [Python profiling](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) to work out where the time is being spent.

Comment: Thanks spookylukey. I edited to specify that the total SQL time is about 2 tenths (far less than 1 second). Also the only extra content processor is the i18n one (tried removing it). I'm installing django-debug-toolbar

Answer (score 1):

Finally the problem was a process running in the server and consuming 98% of CPU. So nothing to do with django, but just in case this helps anyone.